# Почему появляется синтаксическая ошибка?

Tags: php, дата

Почему появляется синтаксическая ошибка в данном фрагменте кода? Пишет, что после идентификатора date не ожидали увидеть '('.

```
function __construct($name, $date = date('Y.m.d')){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->date = $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function __construct($name, $date = null){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->date = $date??date('Y.m.d');
}
```

Comment: А почему именно так? Я понял, что этот оператор возвращает значение по умолчанию если это null. Но почему изначально ошибка появлялась?

Comment: можно и иначе, это один из вариантов. а функцию - нельзя.. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Comment: Ааааааа. Я понял)
Спасибо большое.